# Jenkins: How to prevent next step if triggered job failed?

Tags: jenkins

I need to have the following in jenkins:

- 3 jobs

  - job-a
  - job-b
  - job-c
- job-a should trigger job-b and then job-c
- job-c should not run if job-b failed

I am using

`Fail this build step if the triggered build is worse or equal to FAILURE` in every execution trigger.

However, when I set this up, I get the following log:

```
Waiting for the completion of job-b
job-b #60 completed. Result was FAILURE
Waiting for the completion of job-c
job-C #14 completed. Result was SUCCESS
```

which clearly shows job-c still ran even after job-b failed.

What else am I missing?

Comment: Have you configured your jobs to trigger the next ones as a 'Post Build Step'?

Comment: @SevenEleven no. I used "add build step" ==> "Trigger/call builds on other projects"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one option to solve this problem.

**Option 1**
The easiest way for this scenario would be to configure each job to trigger the next one in a *Post-Build Step*. Then you can specify if the following job should be triggered, depending on the jobs state, like this:

[image: Post-Build Step]

That means, you would configure `job-a` to trigger `job-b` *even if the build fails* and `job-b` to trigger `job-c` *only if build succeeds*.

This solution is kind of 'quick and dirty' and doesn't exactly fit your requirements. Even, in case you will have much more jobs, it will become burdensome to manage them.

**Option 2**
Another option is to use the [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin).

After you have installed the plugin, you would create your `job-a` by selecting *MultiJob Project*. Then you have to add a *MultiJob Phase* as a Job Phase. There you add your jobs (`job-b` and `job-c`) and set *Kill the phase on* to *Falure*/*Unstable* for `job-b`:

[image: multijob phase]

Comment: I really need job-a to trigger job-b and then job-c - is there no way to do that?

Comment: As suggested, you can do this with the additional plugins. They are easy to install. You could then configure a 'multiple jobs'-buildstep (triggering `job-b` and `job-c`) and configure it to 'abort' after job-b failed.

Comment: The multijob plugin looks good. I will give it a try, and if gives me what I need I will accept your answer. thanks!

Comment: @guymograbi I added some more details to my answer.